# how to auto resize in pyqt4 python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

[image]

I want to auto resize the above picture at the size shown below when user resize the main window.

Is there any function to do this in `pyqt4`?

[image]

I was searching for an answer to this problem... but i can't find something related.

I've tried to set fixed minimum size but this doesn't work.

How to auto resize a window in `pyqt4` (python)?

pictures is got in qtdesigner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the QtDesigner, then its really easy. Have a look at layouts like `vertical layout, horizontal layout`
Follow step:

```
1. Add layout to your main window.
2. Right click main window and click 'layout vertically' as you want button below 
   the text area
3. Then add(drag-n-drop) your text area inside vertical area.
4. Add button and what not....
5. Have a look at  'http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-layouts.html' google for    
   properties of layout like alignment of element. size, orientation.
```